# Angular 2: [ngClass] update condition in the function

Tags: angular, data-binding, ng-class

I have a service that pull in a list of menu items and in *ngFor I load the items.  The list of menu items includes also the status of the menu item.

**service**

```
  buttonlist = [
            {id: 1, menu: 'me', status: 'active',children: 2,3,4 },
            {id: 2, menu: 'home', status: 'nonactive'},
            {id: 3, menu: 'contact', status: 'nonactive'},
            {id: 4, menu: 'location', status: 'nonactive'}
];
```

**component**

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let button of buttons "  [ngClass]="'active' == buttons[subButton].status ? 'active' : 'hide'"
(click)="execCommand(button)"
> 

    {{button.id}}

        <ul *ngFor="let subButton of button.children " >
        <li
        (click)="execCommand(button)"
        [ngClass]="'active' == buttons[subButton].status ? 'active' : 'hide'"
> 
            {{buttons[subButton].status}} </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

component functions

```
execCommand(button){
button.status = 'non-active'; 
}
```

If I log button status it does show that I have updated the object data but it is not rendered. How do make this button update status  to show the active class?

My menu is basically id 1 is top level and the rest are children and onclick I would like to remove active on all the sibling children and only eave active the button i clicked, unless I click on top level than just have the top level active and all children.

- 1
- - 2
- - 3
- - 4

I am not using routing, as I got one page application with several levels of menu items and if user clicks it loads a tab.

Comment: I created a functioning plunker, could you please clarify what are you trying to achieve?
https://plnkr.co/edit/wvDSzf2mHu39NLkVhc2I?p=preview

Comment: When a user clicks on siblings ( Either top level, or sub level), it turns other sibling to no active and the item that it clicks on to be active.

Comment: I updated the plunker that so it looks pretty similar to what you described https://plnkr.co/edit/wvDSzf2mHu39NLkVhc2I?p=preview

Comment: strange, if I do console log I see the object updated but in my browser it still shows false :(. Is there anything specific you add to get it updated on the browser?

Comment: Karser, can you do it as a answer so I can mark it as right answer. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the thing that is called event propagation. When you click on the child item, `execCommand(subButton)` is being called. But then the click event goes to the parent item and calls execCommand(button), so it makes all children `active=false`. That's why I added `(click)="execCommand(subButton, $event)"` and also `$event.stopPropagation()` in the click handler.

```js
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let button of buttons "  [ngClass]="button.active ? 'active' : 'hide'"
(click)="execCommand(button, $event)"
> 

    {{button.id}}(active: {{button.active|json}})

        <ul *ngIf="button?.children" style="z-index: -1;" >
        <li *ngFor="let subButton of button.children"
        (click)="execCommand(subButton, $event)"
        [ngClass]="subButton.active ? 'active' : 'hide'"> 
            {{button.id}}(active: {{subButton.active|json}}) 
        </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
  `
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  buttons = [
    {id: 1, menu: 'me', active: true, children: [
      {id: 5, menu: 'sublvl1', active: false},
      {id: 6, menu: 'sublvl2', active: false},
      {id: 7, menu: 'sublvl3', active: false},
      ] },
    {id: 2, menu: 'home', active: false},
    {id: 3, menu: 'contact', active: false},
    {id: 4, menu: 'location', active: false}
  ];
  constructor() {}
  
  ngOnInit() {}
  
  execCommand(button: any, $event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.buttons.forEach(b => {
      b.active = false;
      b.children && b.children.forEach(b => b.active = false);
    });
    button.active = true; 
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even simplify this code by using conditional class attributes for angular2.
please go through this plunkr link : https://plnkr.co/edit/9ayyAl?p=preview

> app.component.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<div><h2>Hello</h2></div>
               <ul>
                   <li *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="execCommand(button, $event)">
                   <a class="menu" [class.active]="button.active">{{button.id}}-{{button.menu}}</a>        
                      <ul *ngIf="button.children" style="z-index: -1;" >
                         <li *ngFor="let subButton of button.children" (click)="execCommand(subButton, $event)">
                           <a class="menu" [class.active]="subButton.active">
               {{subButton.id}}-{{subButton.menu}}</a>
                         </li>
                      </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>`
    })
    export class App implements OnInit {
        buttons = [
            {id: 1, menu: 'me', active: true, children: [
               {id: 5, menu: 'sublvl1', active: false},
               {id: 6, menu: 'sublvl2', active: false},
               {id: 7, menu: 'sublvl3', active: false},
                ] },
            {id: 2, menu: 'home', active: false},
            {id: 3, menu: 'contact', active: false},
            {id: 4, menu: 'location', active: false}
            ];

     constructor() {}

     ngOnInit() {}

     execCommand(button: any, $event){
           $event.stopPropagation();
           this.buttons.forEach(b => {
                 b.active = false;
                 b.children && b.children.forEach(b => b.active = false);
           });
     button.active = true;
   }
 }

 @NgModule({
   imports: [ BrowserModule ],
   declarations: [ App ],
   bootstrap: [ App ]
 })

 export class AppModule {}
```

Thank You.